# Semicubical parabola coordinate ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2 \colon y^2-x^3=0\}$. Let $k[C]=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ be the coordinate ring of $C$. I read in a book that $k[C]$ is non a UFD. Is there a not too difficult and deep way to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UFDs are integrally closed. But $t = y/x$ is in $k(C) \setminus k[C]$ and integral over $k[C]$, since $t^2=x$.

**Alternative**: $x \in k[C]$ is irreducible, but not prime: $k[C]/(x)=k[y]/(y^2)$ is not a domain.

Comment: one line proof!!!